# How do you overline numbers in android xml?

Tags: android, xml

I am developing a maths app in which i have to use numbers with bar on top. check this link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overline

Also how to use Exponentiation like in the following link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation in xml file.

Comment: You need to add at least your try, or how far have you got trying it, but surely at least a piece of code. Don't expect SO users to do your work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the perfect solution but it will give you the idea for text overline.

```
public class OverLineTextView extends TextView {

private Paint paint;

public OverLineTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public OverLineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public OverLineTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    float width = getPaint().measureText(getText().toString());
    canvas.drawLine(getTotalPaddingLeft(), getTotalPaddingTop() + 1,
            getTotalPaddingLeft() + width, getTotalPaddingTop() + 1, paint);
}
}
```

Comment: OP's question states `in android xml...`